# Different chi-square answers from application of chi-test

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared, contingency

I have calculated the chi-test for two variables hhldsize and tenure through two functions chi.test and crosstable() (wherein I set expected=TRUE to calculate it below the crosstable). I did so just to double check that I had the same answers and was surprised to find that they were different as the p-values werent the same. Now i'm not sure which one I'm supposed to use in interpreting the graph...

(the two variables are both contained in the object hhldsize.tenure )

Standalone chi-test code and output:

```
> chisq.test(hhldsize.tenure$hhldsize, hhldsize.tenure$tenure, correct=FALSE)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  hhldsize.tenure$hhldsize and hhldsize.tenure$tenure
X-squared = 114.75, df = 10, p-value < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In chisq.test(hhldsize.tenure$hhldsize, hhldsize.tenure$tenure,  :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

CHI TEST THROUGH CONTINGENCY TABLE CODE:
[image: I have added it as a screenshot to maintain the integrity of the contingency table since I'm not skilled enough to paste the code well onto here]

Your help is much appreciated!

[image: Output from using 'simulate.p.value = TRUE' recommended in comments]

Comment: The two tests don't look different to me. You have very small p-values in each (basically 0), and sometimes the way very small values are presented is confusing, but you get the same Chi-squared test statistic.

Comment: i agree. they look the same.standard r output for p-values will not go smaller than 2.2e-16. thats why it denotes it is smaller than that in your first test

Comment: @marius Thank you for your responses, I can understand where you're coming from. Part of my concern was that since there were 5 cell counts with an expected frequency of less than 5 it violated one of the assumptions required for using a chi-square test, so I am supposed to have used a fisher test rather than a chi-square one? Is this right?

Comment: Yes, the test's assumptions are violated so you might want to choose an alternative test. Or you could combine some of the smaller categories, e.g. combine the 5 and 6 or more categories into a "5 or more" category, without losing much information since the 6+ category is already so small.

Comment: Unfortunately combining those two categories isn't an option and I'm not really sure of any other  tests that could show the relationship between the nominal 'tenure' variable and the ordinal 'hhldsize' variable. Any ideas?

Comment: how about `simulate.p.value=TRUE` in `chisq.test()` ???

Comment: @BenBolker I tried this and managed to get the answer I added as an image to the original post...I'm not sure what that now means and whether its reliable as a measure of the relationship between them just as a normal chi-square test would be...could you elaborate that please?

Comment: The question about what to do with small expected numbers is a statistical issue and would rightly go on stats.SE rather than here